# Margin on ItemsControl of virtualizing ListBox not working properly

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I have a problem with a class which extends `ListBox` in Windows Phone 7 Silverlight. The idea is to have a full `ScrollViewer` (black, e.g. fills the whole phone screen) and that the `ItemsPresenter` (red) has a margin (green). This is used to have a margin around the whole list but the scroll bars begin in the top right edge and end in the bottom right edge of the dark rectangle:

[image]

The problem is, that the `ScrollViewer` can't scroll to the very end, it cuts 50 pixels off of the last element in the list. If I use `StackPanel` instead of `VirtualizingStackPanel` the margins are correct BUT the list is no longer virtualizing.

Thanks for any ideas, I've tried a lot but nothing is working. Is this a control bug?

**SOLUTION:** Use the `InnerMargin` property of the `ExtendedListBox` control from the [MyToolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/) library!

C#:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public MyListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyListBox);
    }
}
```

XAML (e.g. App.xaml):

```
<Application 
    x:Class="MyApp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"       
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="local:MyListBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <ScrollViewer>
                                <ItemsPresenter Margin="30,50,30,50" x:Name="itemsPresenter" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

    ...
</Application>
```

**Update 1**

I created a simple sample app: The scrollbar can't scroll at the end... If you change the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to `StackPanel` in App.xaml and it works as expected but without virtualization

[SampleApp.zip](http://rsuter.com/SampleApp.zip)

**Update 2**
Added some sample pictures. Scrollbars are blue to show their position.

Expected results (use `StackPanel` instead of `VirtualizingStackPanel`):

Correct_01: Scrollbar at top

[image]

Correct_01: Scrollbar at middle

[image]

Correct_01: Scrollbar at bottom

[image]

**Wrong examples:**

Wrong_01: Margin always visible (example: scroll position middle)

[image]

Only solution is to add a dummy element at the end of the list to compensate the margin. I'll try to add this dummy element dynamically inside the control logic... Add some logic into the bound `ObservableCollection` or the view model is no option.

**UPDATE:** I added my final solution as a separate answer. 
Checkout the [ExtendedListBox](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExtendedListBox) class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current solution: Always change the margin of the last element of the list...

```
public Thickness InnerMargin
{
    get { return (Thickness)GetValue(InnerMarginProperty); }
    set { SetValue(InnerMarginProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerMarginProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("InnerMargin", typeof(Thickness),
    typeof(ExtendedListBox), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness(), InnerMarginChanged));

private static void InnerMarginChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var box = (ExtendedListBox)d;
    if (box.lastElement != null)
        box.UpdateLastItemMargin();
    box.UpdateInnerMargin();
}

private void UpdateInnerMargin()
{
    if (scrollViewer != null)
    {
        var itemsPresenter = (ItemsPresenter)scrollViewer.Content;
        if (itemsPresenter != null)
            itemsPresenter.Margin = InnerMargin;
    }
}

private void UpdateLastItemMargin()
{
    lastElement.Margin = new Thickness(lastElementMargin.Left, lastElementMargin.Top, lastElementMargin.Right,
        lastElementMargin.Bottom + InnerMargin.Top + InnerMargin.Bottom);
}

private FrameworkElement lastElement = null;
private Thickness lastElementMargin;
protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    OnPrepareContainerForItem(new PrepareContainerForItemEventArgs(element, item));

    if ((InnerMargin.Top > 0.0 || InnerMargin.Bottom > 0.0))
    {
        if (Items.IndexOf(item) == Items.Count - 1) // is last element of list
        {
            if (lastElement != element) // margin not already set
            {
                if (lastElement != null)
                    lastElement.Margin = lastElementMargin;
                lastElement = (FrameworkElement)element;
                lastElementMargin = lastElement.Margin;
                UpdateLastItemMargin();
            }
        }
        else if (lastElement == element) // if last element is recycled it appears inside the list => reset margin
        {
            lastElement.Margin = lastElementMargin;
            lastElement = null; 
        }
    }
}
```

Using this "hack" to change the margin of the last list item on the fly (no need to add something to the bound list) I developed this final control:

- https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/Shared/Controls/ExtendedListBox.cs

(The listbox has a new event for `PrepareContainerForItem`, a property and event for `IsScrolling` (there is also an extended `LowProfileImageLoader` with `IsSuspended` property, which can be set in the `IsScrolling` event to improve scrolling smoothness...) and the new property `InnerMargin` for the described problem...

- https://xp-dev.com/svn/mytoolkit/Shared/Media/ImageHelper.cs

**Update:** Checkout the [ExtendedListBox](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExtendedListBox) class of my MyToolkit library which provides the solution described here...

Comment: @OffBySome: There were some changes to improve the code. See updated code in answer or go to mytoolkit links...

Answer (score 1):

I think what would be an easier way instead of messing with styles is -

First, you don't need top and bottom margins as you shouldn't have Horizontal scrollbars anyway. You can just add these two margins to your listbox directly.

```
<local:MyListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,30">
```

Then, to have a little gap (i.e. your left and right margin) between the listbox items and the scrollbar, you just need to set a left and right margin of 50 in your `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="50,0"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

**UPDATE (Performance Impact!)**

Okay, please keep all your existing code, and then add this line to the `ScrollViewer` inside your custom listbox style.

```
                        <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="Control">
                            <ItemsPresenter Margin="30,50" x:Name="itemsPresenter" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
```

It seems setting `ManipulationMode="Control"` (default one is "System") has fixed your problem, however, doing this might cause a worse performance of the `ScrollViewer`, please take a look at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/02/listbox-scrollviewer-performance-improvement-for-mango-and-how-it-impacts-your-existing-application.aspx). I think it is a bug.

Do you load a lot of data into this listbox? You really need to test the performance on an actual phone. If the scrolling is smooth I think it could be a way to go, if not let me know I will try to think of something else...

Comment: This does not work, because the green margin on top and bottom is always visible... See picture Wrong_01

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is working. I have to test if this impacts performance...

Comment: Yeah definitely, let me know how it goes.

Comment: Performance is very worse. This is not a solution for me, maybe for simple lists, but for a generic listbox control it's not applicable... My list has very complex items inside and the scrolling is not smooth and even jumps back (very strange behaviour...). But thanks for your effort...

Comment: I have just added another possible solution, please check it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Is it virtualizing (haven't tried it)? I think that if `ItemsPresenter` is not directly inside the `ScrollViewer`, it is not virtualizing any more... I tried to put the `ItemsPresenter` in a `StackPanel` and set the margin on the `StackPanel`: It looked correct but was not virtualizing any more... (I have now an acceptable solution, see question end)

Comment: ahh, damn! i shoulda known. btw, have you tried the LongListSelector from the toolkit?

Comment: LongListSelector is not an option for my app.. But thanks for your help. Feel free to use the final classes :-)

Comment: Hehe couldn't really help and hopefully this issue can be addressed in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do when I want to have padding in a ListBox, so for example I can make it occupy the entire screen even the part under a transparent ApplicationBar, but still be able to access the last item in the ListBox - I use a DataTemplateSelector (http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52595#1024547) and define one (or more) templates for regular items and also a template for a PaddingViewModel that defines a certain height. Then - I make sure my ItemsSource is a collection that has that PaddingViewModel as the last item. Then my padding DataTemplate adds the padding at the end of the list and I can also have ListBox items with different templates.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <local:DataTemplateSelector
            Content="{Binding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <local:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
                <DataTemplate
                    x:Key="ItemViewModel">
                    <!-- Your item template here -->
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate
                    x:Key="PaddingViewModel">
                    <Grid
                        Height="{Binding Height}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
        </local:DataTemplateSelector>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

One more thing you have to note - there are some bugs in the ListBox/VirtualizingStackPanel that when your items are not of consistent height - you might sometimes not see the bottom items in the ListBox and need to scroll up and down to fix it. (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/windowsphone7series/thread/58bead85-4324-411c-988f-fadb983b14a7)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea of my question is to find a solution to avoid this "hack". I don't want to force the client of my control to add something into the view model. At the moment I'm using the same hack as you: I'm adding a border control with the missing margin to avoid the problem...

Comment: I agree this is less than ideal. Maybe there are better ListBox implementations out there that do not have this limitations. I either use this or use a regular StackPanel in simpler cases.

Answer (score -2):

Setting margins on `ItemsPresenter` (or any child of a `ScrollViewer`) breaks the internal logic of `ScrollViewer`. Try setting the same value as Padding on the `ScrollViewer`, i.e.:

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="30,50">
    ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Update:** (after looking at the attached project)

In ScrollViewer's template. The binding for the Padding property was set on the main grid of the control and not on the `ScrollContentPresenter` as it's done in WPF\silverlight. This made the scroll bar's position to be affected by setting the padding property. In effect, on the ScrollViewer, setting Padding is equivalent to setting Margin. (Microsoft, why changing templates for the worst!? Was it intentional?).

Anyway, add this style *before* the style of the list box in App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle1"
        TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Disabled" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                        To="1"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                        To="1"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Height="Auto"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                    Minimum="0"
                                    Opacity="0"
                                    Orientation="Vertical"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Width="5" />
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Height="5"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                    Minimum="0"
                                    Opacity="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And add some changes to the style of the list box:

1. Add setter for Padding on the list box: `<Setter Property="Padding" Value="30,50" />`
2. To the scroll viewer in the template, add `Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"` and `Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerStyle1}"`.
3. Remove margin assignment on `ItemsPresenter`.

This introduces another buggy behavior: the scroll bar is not scrolling till the bottom of the screen. Not a major issue compared to clipping the last item, but annoying nonetheless.

Comment: No. This doesn't work... The scrollbars are inside... It's the very same as `<ScrollViewer Margin="30,50">`... I already tried this...

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot with the problem?

Comment: No. This doesn't work. Looks like Wrong_01. The margin must surround around all items. Setting a margin or padding on the ListBox or ScrollViewer will not work, because this will introduce an always visible margin. I need a margin only at the top element and last element of all items...